# Using PHP to read a page and return to client

Tags: php

I have a simple scenario where, I have a URL1 and a URL2 and I want that when I access URL1, i should get the contents with full headers and data of URL2.

I could use a redirect, but i want the browser should show URL1 as the url only. I am looking for a PHP code that can read the URL2 and return it back to the client with all the headers and data.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: What's wrong with using an `iframe`?

Comment: Nice Idea.. I can try that. I am not sure how the headers will behave. Let me try. Thanks.

Comment: .htaccess redirect might also do the trick

Comment: I tried with the headers. However it solves the purpose but it is not crawlable by search engines.

Comment: why not using CURL API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the whole HTML code you can use the `file-get-contents` function

More information about it can be found here : [file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

If you only want to change the address in the user address bar you may use URL Rewriting techniques. It's easy when you have access to the .htaccess file.
This might be useful : [url-rewriting-for-beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

**Note:** this will only work if the url with the content is in your site, otherwise, the rewriting rule in the .htaccess file can't help you and you have to use the first method.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to get the HTML code of another url or you just want to present the url1 in the address bar while the all actual content is from url2?

Comment: Yup either of them will work, while the second statement is more accurate.

Comment: Ok, it worked.. I just used file-get-contents to read the page and echoed it. Thanks.